# how to use grep to search for text strings from a file that contain square brackets?

Tags: grep, square-bracket

I have 2 text files. I am trying to do the following:

1. Loop over all lines of file1
2. Find all lines in file2 where a given line fro file1 is a substring

So I want to do something like this:

```
for l in `cat file1`
do
   grep $l file2
done
```

The problem is that lines in file1 have square brackets that I need to escape. How do I escape `$l`?

Comment: Do you want to pass the pattern as a literal text? `grep -F $l file2`?